# Does JavaScript provide a way to build a new collection with just one property from another collection?

Tags: javascript

In C#, I can do the following:

```
class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

Item[] Items = new[]
{
    new() { Name = "Bob", Email = "Bob@domain.com", Phone = "555-5555" },
    new() { Name = "Carl", Email = "Carl@domain.com", Phone = "555-5555" },
    new() { Name = "Ted", Email = "Ted@domain.com", Phone = "555-5555" },
};

IEnumerable<string> names = Items.Select(i => i.Name);
```

The last line builds a collection of just the names from `Items` ("Bob", "Carl" and "Ted").

Is there a way to do the same thing in JavaScript without writing a loop and building the array yourself?

Comment: `Items.map(i => i.name)`? As long as `Items` is an array of objects like you've shown here.

Comment: You're looking for [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: C# really is the only language that calls the [`map` function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) by the name `Select` :-)

Comment: @Bergi: That functionality was added to C# as part of it's support for LINQ, which can work with databases. Since it also includes `Where()`, `OrderBy()`, `GroupBy()` and many others, it's quite flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar concept in JavaScript and it is called the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) :)

```js
let details = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Steve' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Mike' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Ericson' }
];

console.log(details.map(detail => { return detail.name }))
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't appear the curly braces (`{` and `}`) are required in the `map()` call.

Comment: Its just a function where you use return statement to return the value. In your case, the curly braces and return statement are completely optional.